# Is the bolded comma needed in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas, sentence

Shortly before he murders Duncan in effort to usurp the throne**,** Macbeth experiences a hallucination of the dagger that will be used to dispatch King Duncan.

Comment: Not sure this is on topic here, but yes - it adds a pause and a separation of the two parts of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical case of a sentence starting with a dependent clause.

"Shortly before [...] to usurp the throne." is not a valid sentence, making it a dependent clause (cannot exist on it's own).

The clause must therefore be succeeded by a comma. (see rule 4a, [grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp))